# Write an Antiquine

Tags: code-golf

## Definitions:

I define a "true antiquine" as follows:

> A true antiquine is a non-empty computer program of length `n` which takes no input and produces a copy of every valid program of length `n` in the same language, except the original program.

I define a "modified antiquine" as follows:

> A modified antiquine is a non-empty computer program of length `n` which takes no input and produces a copy of every valid ASCII (0-127/7-Bit ASCII, specifically) string of length `n`, except the original program.

Here's what I mean when I say "produces":

> A program is said to produce a string if it, were it allowed to run for an arbitrary finite period of time, would print and/or save and/or display a string that contains the string to be produced. In other words, the output must only contain the produced string as a substring. Inversely, any string that is a substring of the output is considered produced, and conversely, any string which does not contain a substring has not produced that substring.

---

## Problem:

Write either a true antiquine or modified antiquine. The program doesn't need to finish in any reasonable amount of time, but has to finish eventually.

The program must be at least 20 characters long. If writing a true antiquine, there must be at least two other valid programs of the same length in the same language as that the program is written in.

If writing a "modified antiquine", the character length restriction is lifted, but of course, a bigger score penalty is received.

---

## Scoring:

The lowest score wins. The formula for scoring programs is as follows:

**(Bytes of Code) [ * 10 if a modified antiquine ]**

Comment: I like the concept of this question, but I dislike the penalizing of esolangs. This has been discussed many times on Meta and the answer is always: a golfing language always wins but so what? You can get more rep from upvotes for a clever algorithm in a normal language than you can from the green checkmark. Then comes the issue of what is an esolang? Are APL & J esolangs just because they have short programs? The issue here is to find a way of ensuring non-trivial output, as mentioned by @Calvin'sHobbies on Martin's answer. Voting to close. Will delete my own answer if this issue can be solved

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there is currently a major loophole allowing programs that produce no output

Comment: @steveverrill Loophole's closed.

Comment: @steveverrill: I think if your language is listed on http://esolang.org, you can consider it an esolang. Since APL and J are real programming languages (i.e. intended for real programs), they are legitimate. If APL is to be excluded from this challenge it should be because it doesn't use the ASCII character, not because it has short programs.

Comment: Does my program have to terminate eventually?

Comment: How will solutions be verified? The number of 20 length programs is way too large.

Comment: @BrainSteel Eventually. But the restriction that it must terminate is in more of a theoretical sense.

Comment: I'm voting to put this question on hold not because of the loopholes, but because I believe the spec to be unclear. For example, in its current state the true antiquine definition would require all programs containing Unicode to be printed for languages where Unicode is allowed, and for languages where only ASCII 0-127 is allowed a modified antiquine is also a true antiquine, since it's not required that non-programs are not printed. The producing definition also makes little sense, since if `abc` and `def` are programs, then the output `abcdef` also produces `bcd` and `cde`.

Comment: I think this question could be interesting if the various problems could be resolved. Have a [meta discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5108/preserving-antiquine-for-antiquity).

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 2400

```
'¡G42#{(_128b:co0c24*o}h
```

This takes advantage of what seems to be yet another loophole in the question. My code contains the character `¡` (codepoint 161 in Unicode or ISO-8559-1) to avoid checking if the output may produce the original source codes).

Also, after every program with 24 or less bytes, 24 NUL bytes are printed to avoid generating the original source code as part of two outputs and to make sure all strings starting with a run of NUL characters are generated.

## How it works

```
'¡        " Push a non-ASCII character.                   ";
G42#      " Push I := 16 ** 42 = 128 ** 24.               ";
{         " Do:                                           ";
  (_      " Decrement I and push a copy.                  ";
  128b:co " Get the associated ASCII string and print it. ";
  0c24*o  " Print 24 NUL bytes.                           ";
}h        " While I is positive, repeat.                  ";
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, 392 * 10 = 3920

Nobody's submitted a true answer yet, so I'll offer up a baseline solution:

```c
char*s="char*s=%c%s%c;n;main(){char b[999],t[392]={0};sprintf(b,s,34,s,34);while(1){n=0;while(n<392&&t[n]==127)t[n++]=0;if(n==392)break;t[n]++;if(strcmp(b,t)){for(n=0;n<392;n++)putchar(t[n]);putchar(10);}}}";n;main(){char b[999],t[392]={0};sprintf(b,s,34,s,34);while(1){n=0;while(n<392&&t[n]==127)t[n++]=0;if(n==392)break;t[n]++;if(strcmp(b,t)){for(n=0;n<392;n++)putchar(t[n]);putchar(10);}}}
```

**Testing is not recommended outside of a debugging environment--this program will not terminate on its own for the foreseeable future.** Prints every combination of 392 characters that *isn't* the source, separated by newlines. Because the source contains no newlines, the full source will never appear in the output. I've run it through most of the tests I can think of, and it seems to work, but this is of course difficult to verify. This program is essentially a modified quine--rather than printing the source out, it saves it in the string `b`. It generates a unique string, checks it against `b`, and outputs it if it is different. This could probably be shortened a bit.

Comment: [330 bytes](https://tio.run/##zU7NCsIwDL7vKUTYaGwFp4KM2icZO2zFaZHV2WZ4kD37TNd58A3MIfmS74fo7VXradK32m28Wi8z1alPtQzbqimLoqgElodiX8muNpZZeLcPx3zvjMWWNcKLw3FuIKVHp7uejghZ9nIGLywXKMgNvB8wZLJ8BzHCqp20Z@IyLG2lVL4/SSDIeUWMaUmggrNxl/oug4ZzOY7r/31tmhgkCaMCKkIQUFxnFFmYIVvYqPyVxoDlDl/hbEyS52DwAw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")